# How can I upload data into a high-replication GAE app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Until now, I've been using the [bulkloader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) to upload data into an app, but I've noticed that Google has added a warning that the bulkloader is intended for use with the master/slave datastore:

> Warning: This document applies to apps that use the master/slave datastore. If your app uses the High Replication datastore, it is possible to copy data from the app, but Google does not currently support this use case. If you attempt to copy from a High Replication datastore, you'll see a high_replication_warning error in the Admin Console, and the downloaded data might not include recently saved entities.

Is there a recommended way of getting data into and out of an app that uses the HR datastore?

Comment: I think that warning refers to downloading data, rather than uploading it. But in any case, it should still work. The only caveat being, as it says, that the downloaded data might not include recent saved entities (due to replication). If this is a concern, you can disable datastore writes from Application Settings (if this is a viable options for you of course!)

Comment: Hope you're right. The warning does have an emphasis on downloading data, but also begins with "This document applies to apps that use the master/slave datastore."